# HTTPS 301 while on CloudFlare w/ Flexible SSL (Apache)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cloudflare

I am trying to have all variations of my root domain 301 (properly) to the https:// version while using CloudFlare w/ Flexible SSL enabled and hosted on an Apache webserver.

My goal is for the following versions to always 301 to https:// domain.tld version ...

1. http:// domain.tld
2. http:// www.domain.tld
3. https:// www.domain.tld

Here is the current code I have...

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews 
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"' [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ https://domain.tld%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Here is the documentation CloudFlare provides for those on "Flexible SSL"; can someone please assist me with this? It will be useful for almost every domain I have w/ CloudFlare enabled. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you just trying to use the Always Use Https:// option found in your CloudFlare PageRule settings?